# show differences between file and file in (compressed) tar archive

Tags: tar, diff, vimdiff

Say I have unpacked a gz-compressed tar file, and do not remember what changes I made to the unpacked files,
or I archived a folder a while ago and want to know what has changed to the files since.

I can use `tar -zd` to get an overview. Then, say it shows me file `foo` has changed.
How can I see the changes in this file, i.e. the difference between the file on my file system and the (older) file in the archive (ideally in vimdiff, but diff output would be fine too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the compressed tar file in vim, move the cursor to `foo` and hit Enter. Then execute

```
:vert diffsplit local/path/to/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `tar ... -O` along with process substitution in bash.

```
diff ... <( tar ... -O ... file.ext ) file.ext
```

Comment: obtaining a diff with one command line is also nice; after some playing around (not sure how/why it works) `diff <(tar -xzOf archive.tgz dir/file.ext) dir/file.ext` gave me the correct result

Comment: (correction: I think I do understand it, `<( ... )` transforms the stdout of ... into a file)